# How to call external js file variable in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js file.

**File Name:** propoties.js

```
function simple()
{
    alert("simple");
    var text = "Control";
}
```

These is my html code. What i want is alert that **text** variable in html.

```
<html>
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/propoties.js'></script>    
<script>
    simple();
    alert(text); /* It is not working */
</script>
 </html>
```

Please help me these. 
Thank you.

Comment: The `text` variable is declared within the `simple()` function. I suggest you read about Javascript variable scope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your js file:

```
var simple=function(){
   var textMultiple = {
        text1:"text1",
        text2:"text2"
    };
   return textMultiple;
}
```

In your html:

```
<html>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='./relative/path/to/propoties.js'></script>    
    <script>
      alert(simple().text1);
      alert(simple().text2);
    </script>
 </html>
```

here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rFmR0XxQtSPt0YPSCYxA) demo.

Comment: It's multiple variables. How to call?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i gave the up vote. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i am glad it helped... dont forget to vote up answers that helped and select the answer by clicking the tick below it. and if you want to stick to javascript, you should learn its scope. [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/) is good article for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alert the text in external file you need to declare the variable as global like below.

```
var text = "Control";
function simple()
{
    text="Changed";
    alert("simple");   
}
```

or you can declare the variable using window keyword

```
function simple()
{
    alert("simple");   
    window.text = "Control";
}
```

**please check in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/HjkwlcnkPwJZ7yyo55q6?p=preview**

Comment: please alert as 
alert(window.text ) after calling simple() function

Comment: First you make sure whether the include path of external js file is correct.

Comment: It shows simple alert. Path of external js file is correct.

Comment: So, both of my code will work, I have checked in my system

Comment: Can you provide any jsfiddle please? Still it's not working.

Comment: you should avoid adding variables to the global window object as much as possible. encapsulation is encouraged. declare variables inside function scope, return it and access it only when it is required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i gave the up vote. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you got the answer :)

Comment: I gave two tick mark to you. Because you answered the question very fast. Thank for wonderful job.

Answer (score 1):

like you did it the "text" variable is only set in the scope of the function "simple" .

you should make the "text" variable global by declaring it outside the function.

```
var text = "";

function simple()
{
    alert("simple");
    text = "Control";
}
```

Comment: sorry but it is working. there may be another error somewhere else in the code .... do you get any other JavaScript errors ?

Comment: Can you provide any jsfiddle please? Still it's not working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i gave the up vote. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the variable globally will work.
ie

```
var text = "";
function simple()
{
     text = "Control";
}
```

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/b9KQbRcHhn4EglHtpUQJ?p=preview)

Comment: Its too late the answered that question. Thanks for your answer, I gave the tick you Thank you.